# App no se ejecuta en el movil pero si en emulador ¿Qué está mal en el código?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

He intentado hacer un reproductor de audio simple sin interfaz de reproducción, cogiendo un poco de aquí y alla, que cogiera las canciones de la tarjeta SD y la agregara a una lista, y al pulsar sobre una canción se reproduzca automáticamente y al volverlo a pulsar sobre la misma canción pues que se pause, el problema está en que en el movil no se me ejecuta...

En el móvil tengo el android `nougat` y me sale la app se ha detenido, aquí les dejo el código:

```
ListView lv;
String[] items;
MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);

    final ArrayList<File> canciones = EncontrarCanciones(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

    items = new String[canciones.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < canciones.size(); i++){
        items[i] = canciones.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","").replace(".m4a","").toLowerCase();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.canciones,R.id.textView,items);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
            }
            else{
                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<File> EncontrarCanciones(File root){

    ArrayList<File> canciones = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] archivos = root.listFiles();
    for (File lista : archivos){
        if (lista.isDirectory() && !lista.isHidden()){
            canciones.addAll(EncontrarCanciones(lista));
        }
        else {
            if (lista.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || lista.getName().endsWith(".m4a")){
                canciones.add(lista);
            }
        }
    }
    return canciones;
    }
}
```

---

Gracias por las respuestas. Si ya he puesto los permisos en el código y a partir de ahi al menos se ejecutaba la aplicacion pero ahora se detiene al intentar reproducirlo... os dejo lo que ponia en el logcat (no se cuanto tenia que copiar pero he copiado la parte que creo que habla del error)

> 06-10 14:12:30.726 4887-4887/com.bignerdranch.android.reproductorsimple D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   06-10 14:12:30.726 4887-4887/com.bignerdranch.android.reproductorsimple E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                             Process: com.bignerdranch.android.reproductorsimple, PID: 4887
>                                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                 at com.bignerdranch.android.reproductorsimple.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:61)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1718)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4184)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:6769)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:6516)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:1648)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10779)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2859)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2535)
>                                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:6420)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:607)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1889)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3240)
>                                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:569)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11008)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5162)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5014)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4539)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4592)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4558)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4691)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4566)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4748)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4539)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4592)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4558)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4566)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4539)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7098)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7030)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6991)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7208)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>   06-10 14:12:30.727 4887-4887/com.bignerdranch.android.reproductorsimple E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Comment: Igual es la version minima del sdk que es mayor que la version de tu movil

Comment: Tengo un galaxy s8 con el Android Nougat 7.0,  y la sdk minima la tengo en la api 14, asi que no creo que sea eso. Igualmente gracias por la pronta respuesta :)

Comment: Puede ser tambíen por tema de permisos

Comment: En el manifest tengo lo del permiso para acceder a la tarjeta externa, que es el único permiso que necesito no?

Comment: A partir de android 5 o 6 (no recuerdo bien) tienes que pedir permisos tambien por codigo

Comment: El emulador con el que pruebas tiene la misma versión de Android que tu móvil?

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, si efectivamente la version del emulador es menor, por eso funcionara ahi. Y he probado lo de poner los permisos en el código java y ahora al menos me abre la aplicacion y aparece la lista de canciones pero al intentar reproducirlo la app se detiene :(

Comment: El tema de los permisos en tiempo de ejecución tiene su complejidad para ser implementado. Hay un tutorial en inglés de Commonsware que en mi opinión es muy bueno. Por otro lado si la app se detiene, y tenes dudas agrega acá el stack trace. Así es más fácil ver el motivo específico.

Comment: en el log cuando sale el error que pone.

Answer (score 3):

Es importante el uso del [**LogCat**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) si estas desarrollando en Android, esto para no perder tiempo en encontrar un problema que puede ser determinado y solucionado rápidamente.

---

Con respecto a tu problema, si estas haciendo uso de los permisos :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Si usas android 6+, no es suficiente agregar el permiso a tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, tienes que requerir el permiso manualmente, esta es una forma de realizarlo :

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 507;

    private void checkWritePermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // No action!.
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Permiso negado.                                  
                }
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

Se pide únicamente el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ya que es inherente el permiso `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

---

El segundo problema esta especificado aquí

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.bignerdranch.android.reproductorsimple, PID: 4887
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying()' on a null object
>   reference at
>   com.bignerdranch.android.reproductorsimple.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:61)
>   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1718)

Tratas de llamar el método `isPlaying()` en una instancia nula de `MediaPlayer`.

Usas dentro de un listener la instancia de MediaPlayer pero nunca se obtuvo una referencia, por lo tanto su valor es null y provoca el problema.

```
if (mp.isPlaying()){
```

Dentro de `onCreate()` debes crear la instancia, por ejemplo si agregamos un mp3 llamado sonido.mp3 entro del folder /raw de esta forma sr realiza:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonido);
```

Comment: El LogCat es muy muy importante!

Comment: Y en mi caso que la app coge las canciones de la tarjeta sd y las pone en una lista.. como lo haria? : 

mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, ¿?);

Comment: Bueno ya he descubierto como, muchas gracias por la ayuda :)